# Azure DocumentDB async requests issue

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-cosmosdb

Here I'm trying to execute a azure documentdb stored procedure in c#.

```
    static string EndpointUri = "https://asdf.documents.azure.com:443/";
    static string PrimaryKey = "X";
    static DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = doit();
        Read();
    }
    public static async Task<string> doit()
    {

        StoredProcedureResponse<string> sprocResponse = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>("/dbs/eew/colls/fff/sprocs/ggg/", "kamal@enadoc.com");
        return "";
    }
```

I wanted the method call `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync` to be executed a synchronous one. Here is how I did it.

From what i understand this should now work as a synchronous method call because i added await to the request. But it does not work that way.

I'm sure this is happening because of my lack of understanding about async await usage of c#.

I couldn't find a way to resolve this on google.

How can i make this synchronous.

Comment: You probably want to go and change your key in Azure right now; you've just given the internet access to create databases and spend money on your account :)

Comment: @Frans Thanks!. But i changed some characters before posting. I'm not that stupid :).

Comment: Hi, just general advice; best to change it to just xxx before posting. At best you get people like me worrying, at worst you get someone who uses it as a seed to brute force the password... If that account has production data in it and I was your csio I'd insist on it being changed now :)

Comment: Is this a console application? How is it running - manually executed, running as a Windows service, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var x = doit();
```

To

```
 var x = doit().Result;
```

Note; that will work fine in this simple console app, but can cause deadlocks in a real application. If you must make it sync in a real application, you should do something like this;

```
var x = Task.Run(() => doit()).Result;
```

Explaining this goes beyond what I'd easily be able to put in an SO answer, sorry. If you have access to Pluralsight, this is a excellent explanation by Jon Skeet: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/skeet-async.
Otherwise, C# in A Nutshell (the book) or a tutorial online.

Comment: There is also a set of good articles by Stephen Cleary that talk about async pattern in .NET. Here is one example: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html